# Route only api traffic to other AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, network-security-groups

I am new to networking. And I am trying to route only traffic from one VM traffic to another VM. Therefore, I have done this.

I have two AWS EC2 instances as:

- Application Server
- Database Server

And they have their own security groups and I have allowed all traffic is permissible. Now I want to Database_server accepts only `Application_server` traffic not all public traffic. `Database_server` is MySQL which is running on 3306 port.

Suppose:

- Application_server Public IP: 14.233.245.51
- Database_server    Public IP: 15.233.245.51

So I have allowed on port 3306 like this `14.233.245.51/32` for only Database_server but it did not work. It was before this `0.0.0.0/0` and `::/0`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: are they in the same VPC?

Comment: @deosha Yes, they are in same VPC.

Answer (score 0):

First, the application server should communicate with the database server via **private IP address**. This will keep all traffic within the VPC and will enable security groups to work correctly.

Second, **configure the security groups**:

- `App-SG` should be associated with the application server and permit incoming traffic on the appropriate ports for the application (eg 80, 443)
- `DB-SG` should be associated with the database server and permit incoming traffic on port 3306 from `App-SG`

That is, `DG-SG` permits inbound traffic from `App-SG` by referring to the ID of `App-SG`. There is *no need to specify an IP address*. The security groups will automatically recognize the traffic and permit the App server to send traffic to the DB server. Return traffic will also be permitted because security groups are stateful.

You MUST communicate with the database server via private IP address for this to work.

Comment: Thank you for giving the details. But I just want that DB-server would not be accessed by any other IP address. Suppose, only I want to access the DB-server at 3306 port so I found my laptop public IP and put into the MYSQL. Therefore like this way I need. You answer is also good. But I want to deny all other public access also.

Comment: Security Groups deny all inbound traffic by default. You must add rules to the security group to define what traffic is **Allowed**.